# Must I compile all the kernel source code due to some modification to sched.c?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm studying the linux kernel. I have modified sched.c to specify my own scheduling policy. But it takes more than 50 minute to recompile into my custom kernel. Why does I have to compile untouched source code? Is there any way to compile only sched.c?
I type the following commands to recompile the kernel in the directory `/usr/src/linux-version`.

```
sudo make
sudo make modules-install
sudo make install
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what sort of processor(s) are you running?

Comment: Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  T3200  @ 2.00GHz, 32bit

Comment: Try using `make -j 4` instead of just `make`; and perhaps learn about [make-kpkg](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-kernel.en.html) - at least on Debian or Ubuntu...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel makefiles are usually quite clever about not rebuilding unless it's really required.

Are you perhaps also modifying sched.h? I'd expect that file to be included all over the place, so rebuilds are likely. If you're only modifying sched.c it shouldn't be rebuilding everything.

PS: If you're interested in learing about advanced (GNU) make those makefiles are gems. There are a couple of really neat ideas in them.